# Minimum length constraint while allowing null values

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints

Let's say we have the following table structure

```
Name                        Null?    Type          
--------------------------- -------- ------------- 
ID                          NOT NULL NUMBER(15)    
middle_name                          VARCHAR2(255)
```

How can I enforce with a constraint that values insterted in `middle_name` must have a minimum length while still allowing `null` values?

I tried the following constraint

```
ALTER TABLE users
ADD CONSTRAINT check_middle_name CHECK (length(middle_name) > 1)
;
```

but it seems that it has a problem with null values as I get the error

```
SQL Error [2293] [23000]: ORA-02293: cannot validate (middle_name) - check constraint violated
```

Comment: Do **not** name a table  `users`, you will avoid some problems in the future...

Comment: Forget the nulls for a moment.  If you have a minimum length of greater than 1, then you have already disallowed having only a middle initial.  And I personally know people who fit that category.  So, your only _valid_ minimum length is 1.  So with that, anything that is not null will meet your minimum.  So the bottom line is your constraint is pointless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine.  [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=555dc4173fe98c8cf7027b7002058805) is a db<>fiddle, so something else is going wrong.

In `where` and `when` clauses, `NULL` results fail the comparison and are treated as "false".  `CHECK` constraints work differently; only explicit "false" values violate the constraint.  As a result, `NULL` values do not result in a violation.

This is the SQL Standard for check constraints.  And it is also how Oracle works.

Aside from that, eliminating one-character middle names seems like a bad idea.  After all, Harry S Truman's middle name was simply "S", to give one example.

Comment: If you count the [dot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_S._Truman) as well the length is two;) and thanks for the clarification of NULL in constraint that was not obvious for me!

Comment: The "something else" is data that already exists in the table, that violates the constraint. The full error message, at the end, is explicit: *an alter table operation tried to validate a check constraint to* ***populated table that had nocomplying values***. (The OP should have posted the full message - as always.) This is why the OP suspected `null` was the culprit. It wasn't, but something else was.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not caused by `null` in that column. Rather, there is already data in your table that violates the constraint, and that data is rows where `middle_name` has length 1. For example, you may have 'F' for "John F Kennedy" in the column already.

You must decide what you need to do with those existing values that violate your desired constraint. Either you fix them (change them to `null` or to longer strings), **or** you can keep them and enforce the constraint only for future rows. That is very easy to do - add the option `novalidate` at the end of the `add constraint` clause in `alter table` (right before semicolon).

If you add the constraint with the `novalidate` option, you will also still be able to update old rows, even those where the middle name is a single letter - as long as you only update data in *other* columns, the constraint is not applied. You will not be able to update the middle name to a single letter even in the old rows though; any new value IN THAT COLUMN must obey the constraint, even if the "new value" applies to an "old row".